# Можно как нибудь узнать размеры верхнего бара окна в Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Можно как нибудь узнать размеры (высоту) верхнего бара окна в Windows используя WinApi или qt?

Comment: под "верхним баром" понимается размер элемента с названием окна, кнопками minimize и maximize?

Comment: Да, собственно ширина то понятно, а вот высоту бы еще как то вычислить

Comment: Для Qt, например, можно взять размер окна - размер главного layout, если он настроен. Для WinAPI используй совет @mega.

Answer (score 4):

```
RECT rc, rw;
int captionHeight;

GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rw);
MapWindowPoints(hwnd, HWND_DESKTOP, (POINT*)&rc, 2);
captionHeight = rc.top - rw.top;
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно. Например с помощью [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx) и [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633503(VS.85).aspx) можно рассчитать размеры всех границ окна.

Comment: Инструменты перечислили, а ответа нет

Comment: @mega вы неправы. Ответ на вопрос в первом предложении.